# .htaccess "Ignore all rules if link starts with..."

Tags: ajax, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my root folder I have installed wordpress and there is also my submenu.php that can not be loaded with ajax if I use rules for /%postname%/ (in default )

So this is what WP gave me

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>    
# END WordPress
```

What do I need to add so that calling

```
$('#submenu').load('submenu.php?cat=4');
```

works again?

Comment: I ended up using /index.php/%postname%/ since I had no success modifying htaccess and I have no intentions digging into special relationship of ajax and wordpress. Almost pretty links work without problem. If anyone comes up with solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way you should be performing AJAX within WordPress.

I suggest you read up on Using [AJAX within WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX) from the codex.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really good with htaccess, but this

```
RewriteRule !^media/ index.php [L]
```

Will redirect everything except media/* to index, so something like this should work

```
RewriteRule !^yourscript.php index.php [L]
```

Note: I agree with Jason there, using it without htaccess is better.